# How to insert this type of date in column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column StartDate and i need to insert this date

```
INSERT INTO Products(StartDate) VALUES(2001-01-01 00:00:00.000)
```

There but it doesn't work

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using? is it mysql, sql server, postgresql etc.?

Comment: sql server management studio 2018

Comment: Phrases like " but it doesn't work" are ambiguous. If you're getting an error, [edit] your question to include the full error message.

Comment: Fyi SSMS is not a RDBMS it's a client UI to SQL Server which is a RDBMS.

Comment: If you are only concerned about dates, then why use datetime datatype for your column? Don't add more potential problems to your design. And understand that datetime (or date or similar) datatypes have no "format". The values are stored in a binary format and it is the tool you use to view this information that provides a format.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need single quotes around your literal datetime value.

If the millseconds are added depends on the datatype of the column.

```
INSERT INTO Products(StartDate) VALUES('2001-01-01 00:00:00.000')
```

Comment: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CategoryName', table 'nortwind_warehouse.dbo.Products'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: @Максим provide the whole table structure of Products Table.

Comment: @Максим, you need to insert all columns in a table,  that have no default value. in your case you have more column that have to be inserted with a Value, that is not NULL